# What is the best way to have a multiple model based form for account creation in Devise (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

**EDIT NOTE**
I am rewording this question entirely now that I have a bit better understanding of rails & devise.

I am looking for a way to utilize a single table structure (Account) to create various account types.

What I am now having a hard time with is a structure where I need my Business to have an account but not necessarily vice versa (an Account could just be a typical user). I think the easiest approach would be just to have a 1 to 1 relation as opposed to inheritance but I could be mistaken there.

The reason its confusing to me is the registration process. If I accept the account information, I believe I could use  [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) to accept the account information but im afraid that'll break the workflow that devise is expecting. I considered overriding `Devise::RegistrationController` but I don't really know how rails is going to handle that (ie, if I call super but I am dealing with a Business rather than an Account - what happens?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem per-se with having a form which manages multiple models, so long as the models are related to one another.

The 'stock' way of achieving this would be to use 'accepts_nested_attributes_for' in your model.

For your situation, you'd do something like this:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :business
end
```

Then in your registration view, you would use:

```
<!-- validation errors etc -->
<%= form_for @employee do |f| %>
  <!-- all your employee fields etc -->

  <%= f.fields_for :business do |b| %>
    <p>
      <%= b.label :name %>
      <br/>
      <%= b.text_field :name %>
    </p>

    <!-- more fields from business -->
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If you wanted to handle both employee and 'normal user' registration in the same form, you could probably do something like this (never tried this, but I think it should work!):

```
<!-- validation errors etc -->
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  <!-- all your person fields etc, assuming no extras for employee -->

  <% if @person.respond_to? :business %>
    <%= f.fields_for :business do |b| %>
      <p>
        <%= b.label :name %>
        <br/>
        <%= b.text_field :name %>
      </p>

      <!-- more fields from business -->
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

P.S. you mentioned in your question that you were worried Devise wouldn't cope with nested attributes. It definitely does, as I do exactly this in one of my applications.

Comment: Sorry, not sure if this helps - I wrote it just before you reworded the question!

Comment: Ah, I'm really sorry Paul - I tried to get that edit out as quickly as possible!

Comment: At least I was on the right track with using accepts_nested_attributes_for! In your example above, how would you kick off the registration process? Would you actually have the Account (whatever it may be) actually do the updating?

Comment: Since you're now saying you're not going to use interitance, you should be able to do this using Devise's registration action. I've gotta go now, but I'll try and re-write this answer later to cover how I think you could manage it. I assume you want the creation of the business to be optional?

Comment: Paul - I think I understood what you were suggesting on your answer above (although the structure is a bit off, but that was more than likely my fault). I am working through it now and will mark you as the answer if it turns out that is what you meant. I'll also roll the question back and clarify what i did in regards to what you said incase others need this answer as well.

Comment: Awarding you the bounty for helping me see where to go. Thanks man.

Comment: Pleasure. Glad it helped and sorry about the timing mishap with the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CanCan to make account roles, and ask in your code `current_user.role?(:admin)`

There is good app template with device/cancan/spike integrated:

https://github.com/augusto/devise-cancan-spike

Comment: Thanks - roles are what I am more familiar with but that still leaves my confusion. If I create a general User account and then include a role for each type, how do I create a form that handles the account creation on a single form?